# assembly - how to edit an executable

Tags: assembly

i'm totally new to assembly. I am writing a patch for an executable to fix a graphics issue. In particular i need to change the dwExStyle parameter of a window from 0 to 00020000. The hex code of the original instruction is

```
6A 00 (push 0)
```

And when i tried to change it to

```
68 00 00 02 00 (push 00020000)
```

The executable stopped running, and I get an access violation error . How can I edit the parameter of the push command whithout messing the executable?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: whole code executed to call the function:

```
:0055935D 6A00            push 00000000
:0055935F 56              push esi
:00559360 6A00            push 00000000
:00559362 6A00            push 00000000
:00559364 68F9010000          push 000001F9
:00559369 6886020000          push 00000286
:0055936E 6800000080          push 80000000
:00559373 6800000080          push 80000000
:00559378 6A00            push 00000000
:0055937A 683C565700          push 0057563C   |
:0055937F 683C565700          push 0057563C
:00559384 6A00            push 00000000

* Reference To: USER32.CreateWindowExA, Ord:0059h
              |
:00559386 FF1574B15600        Call dword ptr [0056B174]
```

As you can see, the function called is CreateWindowExA from windows API, which should take a dword for the desired parameter (the window style)

Comment: Your new instruction is longer than the old one, so you probably overwrote the instruction(s) that followed it.

Comment: Do you ask how to edit binary in a way it doesn't change a size or you like to add instructions into it? Also your example seems invalid. If the instruction push 0, then 0 should carry the same bitness as your other number (which seems to be 64-bits).

Answer (score 2):

Inserting more bytes that initially, you moved all instructions from this address to the end of the executable by several bytes and then all jump targets was changed.

Patching an executable is not so easy task and is not for a beginner IMHO.

Comment: Sure it's for a beginner.  I believe each person should have a goal to work toward, which possibly may never be reached, but this one seems like pretty low fruit.  Clearly, patching EXE's is their goal, and currently I also have an interest in this.  I would like to edit code at a high level and only edit the relevant instructions, i.e. building code repetitively without having to compile whole functions or modules.  Because the waiting time is what is killing dev times.  It's going to take me a year of just waiting for rebuilds (C++ / VS) it's ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

If you are totally new to this: Assembly is a language - the binary code instructions are in the executable, compiled from the ASM files.

If you have to patch the binary, you have to carefully check where the instruction pointer starts and where the parameter to the instruction starts and ends and only modify those bits in the executable file.

**The bad news is**, if you  are really having

```
 6A 00 (push 0)
```

This is a push byte argument and you can not replace it directly with dword push 00020000,

**EDIT:** to clarify, if it really is using byte push then it is some sort of C/C++ compiler optimization and the odds are there is not much you can do about it.

**EDIT 2:** operand 6A pushes immediate byte into a stack, but the stack pointer is still [probably decremented by 4](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~patt/14s.382N/problemset/project/faq.html), so this part was of my answer was most likely wrong: *"also the function which will receive the argument will assume a byte is coming out of the stack, which will cause stack buffer to go out of sync and the access violation is just waiting around the corner."*

Answer (score 2):

If you have some space left in the binary which is safe to overwrite (look for series of '0x90' no operation instruction) you could write instructions to prepare the arguments and jump back right before the function expecting dwExStyle is called. Or call the function yourself and skip the original function at all. You would replace the first bytes of the function to patch with a 'jump' instruction to your newly inserted instructions.

Comment: The problem may still be that the function to be called is waiting a byte from stack, so pushing DWORD instead of BYTE just messes up the rest of the params - no?

Comment: It would, but from the name of the parameter i assume that the function awaits a DWORD. I guess there are more push instructions happening before the function is called to assure functionality but I cannot say this for sure. Maybe Ukk can post the assembly.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I'm wrong, the 6A byte push may actually decrement ESP by 4 resulting as DWORD push, so the trick might work